# Multiplexing of resistance measurements

Tags: microcontroller, resistance, measurement

I'm designing a circuit that requires me to measure three low value (8-60 ohms) resistors with a hard wired common connection on one end. My ADC doesn't have enough inputs to measure all three at once along with everything else it needs to do.

My two questions are:

1. What's the best method of current measurement? A Wheatstone bridge will draw way too much power, so I'm leaning towards a constant current source, and measuring the (amplified) voltage drop over the resistors. At 20mA (I don't want to go much higher as the resistors may warm up and change resistance) this gives me a voltage drop range of 0.16-1.2V.
2. How should I switch between resistors? Automatic switching is required as this device needs to be a one-button operation - plug in sample, press button, receive information label. Is there a better option than two SPDT relays?

Thanks!

Comment: Related thread about muxing a current source for excitation: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408469/switching-a-current-source-through-a-mux/408547#408547

Answer (score 1):

Get a dual 3:1 analog multiplexor. (Or 4:1)

Wire the first 4:1 to each of the 4 resistors, with the common node to Current Source.

Wore the 2nd 4:1 also to each of the 4 resistors, with the common node to ADC Vin+.

Tie the ADC Vin- to "GND". I presume you can implement a 10 milliohm Ground connection between the 3 resistors. The value of 10milliOhm * 20mA is an error of 200 microVolts out of 0.16 volt, or error of 0.16/0.0002 = 1/800 or 0.125% error due to GND plane/GND wiring resistance.

Comment: I'm not keen on passing current through muxes. Having found this article, this seems like my best solution: https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1278370

Answer (score 0):

Create a 20 mA current source and set up a mux with 2 control lines. Have your micro loop through the control lines 00 through 11 (for 4 total combinations, one of which you're not using) as often as necessary. Since the micro is giving out the control signals, you know which muxed input you're looking at at any given time. You can therefore read the value with the ADC for each resistor to which the current source is applied at the moment. Use high-precision, low-drift resistors.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've got already. How would you build the mux - relays?

Comment: Why do you want to use relays? Your mux(es) would be doing all the switching. You wouldn't need any additional switching hardware as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't have any muxes, that's why I'm asking. All the muxes I've seen have non-zero internal resistance (mostly 50 ohms and 1K in some cases), which means they're absolutely no good for measuring with a constant current source.

Comment: "they're absolutely no good for measuring with a constant current source". That's simply not true. Think about it: all you care about is the current passing through the resistors you want to measure, to develop a voltage corresponding to temperature across said resistor. Parts with 0 internal resistance are ideal parts that don't exist. Consider a much smaller current (1-5mA) to generate less heat in your mux(es), and measure the voltage across your resistors. Even if the internal mux resistance is unknown, the constant current will give a repeatable voltage on your measurement resistors.

Comment: To put @schadjo 's advice into other words, '4-terminal' resistance measurements work great through muxes.

Comment: Pulling current through a mux sounds like a bad idea. Surely the internal resistance of the mux will limit the current through the resistor?

I feel a better solution is to mux the voltages instead. I can tie one side of the differential amplifier to common, and then mux the other side and use the mux to sample the voltages.

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking about: https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1278370

Comment: "Pulling current through a mux sounds like a bad idea." That's was my gut instinct too. But it's used in industrial equipment, and its why these devices' datasheets have wattage and internal resistance ratings, because you *can* pull current through them.

Comment: That said, the eetimes circuit is interesting, but it doesn't route the current through each resistor; it looks at each resistor's voltage in turn. You either need 3 current sources or have to stack your resistors, which would effectively reduce your ADC resolution to 1/3. For separate sources, you'd have to account to variations in output current too between sources. If you had 2 muxes, 1 mux to route a single current source to each load in turn and 1 mux to route the resultant voltage signal to the adc, you could save space and improve resolution (though perhaps not money; adcs are pricey).

Comment: The eetimes idea would definitely work for a quick and dirty measurement.

Comment: Another issue here is with the channels that are "off" on the MUX.  These channels will induce a large voltage on the mux inputs (current source into high resistance = large voltage) and when this voltage reaches the voltage limit on the MUX the protection circuits will switch on and the signal will leak through.  Depending on the output impedance of the current sources, this may be small, but it's there.  I recently built a PCB that demonstrated this effect with photodiodes and the ADG706 :-(  I think the solution is either resistors or a current return path for each current source.

Comment: See the answers here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408469/switching-a-current-source-through-a-mux/408547#408547